# Populating Object array with new Objects

Tags: java, arrays, object

I'm trying to populate an object array with new objects. Here is the code:

Main class

```
public class Bejeweled extends JFrame{

public Bejeweled(){
    Board board = new Board();
    getContentPane().add(board);
    board.start();
}

public static void main(String[] args){
    Bejeweled game = new Bejeweled();
}
```

Board class

```
public class Board extends JPanel{

final int BOARDHEIGHT = 8;
final int BOARDWIDTH = 8;
Gem[] gems;

public Board(){
    gems = new Gem[BOARDHEIGHT * BOARDWIDTH];
}

public void start(){
    fillBoard();
}

public void fillBoard(){
    Arrays.fill(gems, new Gem());
    for(Gem gem : gems){
        System.out.println(gem.type); //**This was expected to print random numbers**
    }
}
}
```

Gem class

```
public class Gem {

public int type;

public Gem(){
    this.type = genType();
}

public int genType(){
    return (int) (Math.random() * 7);
}

}
```

The problem is that all objects appear to be the same. I know I should encapsulate type in the Gem class, but I'm trying to limit the amount of code I'm posting here.

A new Board gets created from the main class, in the Board class a Gem[] is filled with newly created Gems (class Gem).

Comment: Consider `Arrays.fill(gems, new Gem());`. In this line you create a single gem, and use the same gem to fill the array. Have you considered using a for loop instead?

Comment: Use [`Arrays.setAll`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Arrays.html#setAll-T:A-java.util.function.IntFunction-).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Arrays.fill` fills the array with the value you provide, which in this case is a particular instance of `Gem`. Instead, you need to use a `for` loop and set each of the array elements to a distinct `Gem`:

```
for(int i = 0; i < gems.length; i++) {
    gems[i] = new Gem();
}
```

Note that if you really have an 8x8 board, it's much preferable to have a `Gem[8][8]` than a `Gem[8*8]`.

Comment: Or [`Arrays.setAll`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Arrays.html#setAll-T:A-java.util.function.IntFunction-).

Comment: Thanks, yes, in my current version of the code I already use a two dimensional Object array, but thanks anyway :)

Comment: setAll doesn't seem to exist for Object @BoristheSpider

Comment: @RichardKoetschruyter it does. I linked to it.

Comment: @BoristheSpider It exists only if the author is using Java 8.

Comment: @JamesB that's a safe assumption. Java 8 has been out for over a year now. I think people should explicitly state that they are _not_ using Java 8 now.

Comment: mmm not sure about that. You would be surprised how much Java 6 and 7 is still out there.

Comment: @JamesB I wouldn't be at all surprised. But we, as the Java teaching community, should be moving on. The onus is on the question asker to explicitly state that they are using outdated software.